# Make RDP & VNC work within home LAN network?

Tags: remote-desktop, wireless-router, lan, port-forwarding, vnc

I just need to open up posts/ forwards/ triggers on both Routers, not sure exactly HOW:

- RDP: 3389
- VNC: 5900

I've already tried a few googled tutorials. It's not working.

The machines can access each other over Ethernet but not when the Notebooks cant access the desktops when connected via WiFi on the routers.

**Network:**

`ISP > Tomato USB FW on ASUS RT N16 WiFi > GigE Switch > (via LAN port) TP-Link WR740N WiFi`

- Tomato ASUS - DHCP Server with Static DHCP assigning fixed IPs
- TP-Link also has Tomato assigned Static DHCP assigned IP: 192.168.100.Y
- All machines are on common Subnet 192.168.100.X

**Machines:**

- Notebooks connected via WiFi on both Wireless Routers
- Desktops connected to GigE Switch

  - **Windows Machines:** Allowed Remote Access / RDP + Installed Tight VNC
  - **Ubuntu/ Mint:** Native Access via VNC enabled

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds to me like you are using the exact same IP subnet on different network segments.

If your WiFi Router does not bridge Ethernet frames from and to Wired and Wireless Network you need to use two different networks, otherwise your setup cannot work because your client always assumes 192.168.100.x to be on the local network and will never send the packets to the router.

From a security point of view I suggest to use different networks on WiFi and wired networks. E.g. 192.168.100/24 on Wired and 192.168.101/24 on WiFi network. If a wired client now wants to access the notebooks the IP packet is routed to the default gateway (IP of the router), which forwards it to the WiFi network, if you have appropriate firewall rules and forwarding.